# AltBeacon getIdentifier returns wrong value

Tags: java, android, altbeacon, beacon

I have a problem with my code or beacon returning a "wrong" value (in quotes, as this is most likely a mistake in my code). I have been reading up on beacons, and as far as I understand, I can give my beacons 3 identifiers. I have configured my beacon's identifiers to 000000000000001234 (lots of 0s, ending with 1234), 0001 for major and 0002 for minor.

Here is some code Im using while ranging beacons:

```
String id1 = beacon.getId1().toString(); 
String id2 = beacon.getId2().toString();
String id3 = beacon.getId3().toString();
```

I was assuming that these would represent the identifiers I had in my beacon, but the value I get for id1 is "0x02676f6f2e67c...", and id2 and id3 are null. Am I totally off?

Maybe I am using a wrong parser? (I got this in a mail from the beacon customer support, although I did not specify that I wanted to use the identifiers)

```
.setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v"));
```

I must admit, I dont quite get if the beacon parser depends on HOW I want to decode my beacon, or on WHAT kind of beacon Im having, or maybe even both..

For the record, I am using Android, but I assume this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

- There are several popular beacon formats, each of which transmit a different number of identifiers with different identifier lengths.  AltBeacon and iBeacon send three identifiers of 16, 2 and 2 bytes respectively.  Eddystone-UID sends two identifiers of 10 and 6 bytes respectively.  And Eddystone-URL sends a single identifier of a variable length between 1-17 bytes.
- The question doesn't say what beacon format is being transmitted.  It sounds like it is intended to be iBeacon or AltBeacon because those formats have a three part identifier (sometimes called ProximityUUID, major and minor).  But the first identifier of those formats is a 16 bytes UUID, and the example shows an identifier like this: 000000000000001234, which may be 9 bytes if shown in hex, or an unknown number of bytes if expressed in decimal.
- The beacon layout string shown ("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v") is for Eddystone-URL, which is a format with a single variable length identifier, that can be converted to a URL string using a custom compression algorithm.
- The beacon detected with a single identifier (ID2 and ID3 are null) probably is an Eddystone-URL transmission.  The partially shown ID1 of 0x02676f6f2e67c... is equivalent to the URL of "http://goo.g"...

Conclusions:

- The beacon being detected is probably not the one you intend to detect.
- You may have multiple transmitting beacons in the vicinity or a beacon that sends out multiple transmission of different types, which is why you are detecting the Eddystone-URL beacon.
- The beacon transmission you intend to detect is probably not in the Eddystone-URL format, so you probably need a different BeaconParser for this.  You need to figure out the format first so you can add the proper BeaconParser.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the record, I am transmitting iBeacon, UID and URL, so as mentioned here, I was probably getting the URL as a result in my Id1. After digging through my customer support mails, I found another beacon parser they had mentioned that I tried, and I am now correctly receiving the response I want. However, I was not sure where my mistake was before this clarification :)